# Nedarim on Questions and Answers

Tags: halacha, words, nedarim-shevuot

Let's say someone was asked "are you going to shul tomorrow?" and the other person answers "yes." Does that count as a Neder?

BTW Rav Mutzafi says that Nedarim are only on Mitzvot, Torah etc.

Comment: I don't think you are interpreting R. Mutzafi correctly.  There are many cases in m. nedarim dealing with someone who is moder hanaa.

Comment: @YDK Exact language: זה לא נדר , כי רק בעניני מצוות זה נדר , ולא בעניני חול .

Comment: Also, yes you are correct, but it really depends. The Halachot are very complicated. There is even a Gemara in Gitin about this I believe.

Comment: Could you post the case, he say "ze lo neder".  That may clarify his intent.

Comment: לכבוד הרב אם אמרתי שאני לוקחת על עצמי לא להתקשר לבן אדם עד ש.. ולא אמרתי בלי נדר האם זה נדר שאני צריכה לקיים?

Comment: One could interpret that as saying that since she did not use a language of neder or shevua, it doesn't take hold.  But when there is a mitzva, even a weaker language is sufficient.  (I'm not saying he is saying that, but it's an example of an interpretation that is more plausible than "nedarim are only on mitzvos.)

Comment: @YDK agreed....

Comment: If that is, in fact, what the Rav meant, the answer to your question may be different that someone answering yes to "Are you going to the market tomorrow?"

Comment: see http://www.ou.org/torah/article/sat_01_05_13

Comment: Could you please give reference for the R' Mutzafi teshuva?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not a neder, as per Nedarim 2b:

> דתנא נדרים דמיתסר חפצא עליה... לאפוקי שבועה דקאסר נפשיה מן חפצא
>
> It taught nedarim where one forbids an object on himself, and excluded shevuot where one forbids one's self from the object.

It might be a Shevua, though, as per Shevuos 3:1:

> שְׁבוּעוֹת שְׁתַּיִם שֶׁהֵן אַרְבַּע, שְׁבוּעָה שֶׁאֹכַל וְשֶׁלֹּא אֹכַל, שֶׁאָכַלְתִּי וְשֶׁלֹּא אָכַלְתִּי.
>
> There are two types of Shevuos, which are four: A Shevuah that I will eat or will not eat, that I ate or that I did not eat.

Your case would be comparable to "I will eat." The problem is that all throughout Shevuos we find that a Shevuah can only be made in one of two ways: actually swearing to that effect (every case is introduced as "Shevuah that I...") or someone adjuring you to swear, to which you answer "Amen" or some other form of acceptance (Rambam, Shevuos 2:1ff). Because of this, it would seem that it is not considered a Shevuah, either.

Comment: IMHO the question is based on the Tosfot Nedarim 8a.